# Significant difference in runtimes of finding a key in a HashMap, using two similar blocks of codes

Tags: java, hashmap, runtime

I used HashMap.containsKey to check whether a key exist in a HashMap and calculated the duration in the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("one", 1);
    map.put("two", 2);
    map.put("three", 3);
    if(map.containsKey("four")){
        System.out.println("true");
    }

    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long duration = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println(duration);
}
```

**The duration was: 48278**

I used HashMap.containsKey to check whether a key does NOT exist in a HashMap and calculated the duration in the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("one", 1);
    map.put("two", 2);
    map.put("three", 3);
    if(!(map.containsKey("four"))){
        System.out.println("true");
    }

    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long duration = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println(duration);
}
```

**The duration was: 378741**

So in the first code I check whether a key ,"four", exists in my map and in the second code I check whether a key does NOT exist in the map (Check line seven).
Why is runtime so longer in the second one? Aren't they basically doing the same thing?

Comment: Just remove the `System.out.println("true");` and see the diff

Comment: @Eklavya Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your example this this difference is caused by using System.out.println(). This takes time and should be the main cause of it.

Anyways, your measurement method is bad. Execution times might heavily vary from time to time. This is due many factors, i.e the JVM's JIT or CacheMisses of the CPU. If you measure the exection time only once, the result is inaccurate. If you execute your code
hundreds of thousands of times, these incosistencies add up to zero.